# ¿los registros de logs afectan en la capacidad de webLogic?

Tags: java, xdebug

Mi aplicación consiste en el envio de email y en esos se adjunta un pdf el cual en los registros log se imprime una cadena en b64 que corresponde al archivo pdf.
Mi aplicacion se detiene porque el webLogic se satura de memoria y deja de funcionar. ¿Cómo evitar que se sature ya que el convertir el pdf en b64 es parte de la libreria javaMail?¿El hecho de que se imprima toda la cadena en los logs causa que se sature la memoria o no tiene nada que ver?

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es un sistema de colas, para que cada petición al server entre a la cola hasta que termine un proceso empiece con otro

Comment: Podrías darme un ejemplo de ello o decirme como y donde se implementa? en el servidor o en la aplicación web?

Comment: Imprimir una fichero ne base64 rn rl log no aporta absolutamente nada y hace el log dificilmente legible. Si puedes evítalo. Pero no por esto se te satura el servidor. Tampoco creo que sea por la conversión del pdf. Intentar hacer alguna medición aunque el weblogic tiene algo pero es bastante malo. Mas no te puedo decir

Comment: @CristinaJuarez aqui hay un tutorial para hacerlo [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSLKT6_7.6.0/com.ibm.mt.doc/emailstner/t_configuring_jms_queues_weblogic.html)

Comment: [Otro enlace](https://willmanortiz.wordpress.com/2016/01/29/creando-queues-en-weblogic/) y esta es mi busqueda en google hay bastante información [google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=crear+colas+en+weblogic)

Comment: Muchas gracias!